# How to Pull Links from Google Search using Selenium, Python

Tags: python, parsing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xml-parsing

I am trying to ask Google to pull up a query's relevant Search Links, in this case I am using Wikipedia, and then parse the urls of the first three via Selenium. So far I have only been able to do the first part, Googling. Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

query = raw_input("What do you wish to search on Wikipedia?\n")
query = " " + query

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# go to the google home page
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awikipedia.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8")

# the page is ajaxy so the title is originally this:
print driver.title

# find the element that's name attribute is q (the google search box)
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

# type in the search
inputElement.send_keys(query)

# submit the form (although google automatically searches now without submitting)
inputElement.submit()

try:
    # we have to wait for the page to refresh, the last thing that seems to be updated is the title

    # You should see "cheese! - Google Search"
    print driver.title

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'Wikipedia')]").click()

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

I am trying to use the example from Selenium's documentation, so please excuse the comments and, at times, unnecessary code.

The line of code I'm having trouble with is:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'Wikipedia')]").click()
```

What I'm attempting to do is obtain the relevant Wikipedia link, or, more specifically, the link that the H3 'r' path directs to.

[Here's a picture of a Google page that I'm describing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxDW5.png)

In this instance, I wish to pull the link http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/salary

Sorry for the wall of text, I'm trying to be as specific as possible. Anyways, thank you for the assistance in advance.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this XPath is not correct - there is an `a` element that has "Wikipedia" inside the text, not the `h3` element. Fix it:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Wikipedia')]").click()
```

You can even go further and simplify it using:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Wikipedia").click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @HillaryDuff this is an incomplete traceback - could you post the complete traceback and the error itself?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/HillaryDuff/Desktop/stackoverflow_ex.py", line 33, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Wikipedia')]").click()
WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (229, 260.75). Other element would receive the click: <div style="width: 957px; height: 1156px; top: 166px;" class="flyr-o" id="flyr"></div>`

Comment: Alexce, the error was longer, but included redundant information about the actual Python Framework. Above, I've plucked out the most important parts of the error. Thanks for the assistance, again :)

Comment: Nevermind! I got it working, I just had to tinker with the code a little bit! It appears your first piece of code was the only working of the two, and I ended up having to use Chrome instead of firefox to get it to work! Thanks so much!